# Delphi Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest RemoteIP VS RemoteAddr

Tags: delphi

`TWebRequest` has two metnod for retrive the client IP Address:

1. RemoteIP
2. RemoteAddr

From [docs of RemoteIP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest.RemoteIP):

> Specifies the IP of the remote target machine associated with the HTTP
>   request message. Read the RemoteIP property to obtain the IP address
>   of the remote target machine associated with the HTTP request message.

From [docs of RemoteAddr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest.RemoteAddr):

> Indicates the remote IP address of the client associated with the HTTP
>   request message. Read RemoteAddr to obtain the IP address of the
>   source of the Web client request.

They seem very close but RemoteIP return an empty string.
I want retrieve the client ip address, what is the right method?

Comment: Interestingly, RemoteIP [does not appear in the list of properties](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_HTTPApp_TWebRequest.html). Maybe it's something they intended to implement at one point, or that is just there because it had to be to meet some ancestor's interface or abstract method. It seems RemoteIP has no real purpose and you should use RemoteAddr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look into source code we will find the following in the declaration of TWebRequest

```
property RemoteIP: string read GetRemoteIP;
property RemoteAddr: string index 21 read GetStringVariable;
```

Implementation:

```
function TWebRequest.GetRemoteIP: string;
begin
  Result := EmptyStr;
end;
```

and GetStringVariable is a virtual method.

Let's look into one of child classes - TISAPIRequest, we will find the following:

```
LResult := GetFieldByNameA(ServerVariables[Index]);
```

ServerVariables[21] is 'REMOTE_ADDR' header, which shows IP of client or proxy server.

But there is no implementation for GetRemoteIP.

It looks like RemoteIP isn't used in requests, because TCGIRequest, TApacheRequest and TWinCGIRequest also don't implement GetRemoteIP.

Comment: Still in Rio 10.3